# Pending call using axios on express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im trying to do a really simple call to an api using axios with express and have no idea why its always pending on browser

This is my route

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
const controller = require("../../controllers/issues.controller");
/* GET ALL ISSUES */
router
  .route('/')
  .get(controller.getAllIssues);
```

This is my controller

```
var axios = require("axios");
const url = "https://redmine-mock-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/issues?after=2019-04-13T12:00";


exports.getAllIssues = () => {
  const res = axios.get(url)
    .then(res => console.log(res.data))
    .catch(err => console.log("Axios err: ", err));
}
```

This is the app.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./src/api/routes/v1/index');
var usersRouter = require('./src/api/routes/v1/users');
var issuesRouter = require('./src/api/routes/v1/issues');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/v1/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/v1/issues', issuesRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

On the browser its always pending and I already trying from .then to await/async and have no idea what im doing wrong. When i had the route and controller on the same file it was working. Anyone with a tip please?

Comment: `getAllIssues` should take two parameters the `request` & `response`, once you've done with fetching your issues attach it to `response` object and `response.send()` to the client

Comment: Thank you so much!`

```
exports.getAllIssues = async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(url)
      res.json(data)
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Axios Error:', err)
    }
  } ```

looking like this and working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is with the controller. Since you never run the `res` variable function (just define it), nothing happens and since the response is not sent back... it is hanging.

```
exports.getAllIssues = (req, res) => {
  axios.get(url)
    .then(axRes => {
        console.log(axRes.data)
        // this below line is what closes the loop on waiting for the controller
        res.json(axRes.data);
    })
    .catch(res.json);
}
```

An async approach would look very similar

```
exports.getAllIssues = async (req, res) => {
   try {
      const axRes = await axios.get(url);
      res.json(axRes.data);
   } catch(err) {
      res.send(err);
   }
}
```

You can read about different express `res.send` methods etc here http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json

Comment: Thats it! Thank you so much! updated for async/await using. Thank You!

Comment: awesome! if you have a sec to mark the answer as correct, I'd appreciate it